# VS2010 "Look at these file types" option keeps resetting to previous value

Tags: visual-studio-2010

One day, in VS2010, I was using the "Find in Files" tool.

I set the "Look at these file types" option to `*.sql`. Ever since then, when I bring up the tool, it will randomly default the file type to either `*.sql`, or blank. I want it to always default to blank.

The "bug" happens across different solutions.

Does anyone know why it's randomly resetting to `*.sql` and how I can get it to stop?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's behaving randomly.  My VS2010 always uses the last file filter I entered, although unfortunately it won't seem to remember me clearing out the option.

To revert it back to blank, use regedit.exe and navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find.  Edit the value named "Filter" and set the data to blank.

Next time you change it to *.sql, though, Visual Studio will store it and remember it.

Comment: Yup, I figured out the registry hack. Thanks for confirming that it works for you. Now it's stuck on *.vb :)

Comment: Just happened to me on VS2012. Answer is the same except it's under \11\

Comment: I call this a bug, and it's an especially annoying one since it only seems to remember what you did last when it's inconvenient, and never when it would be useful.

Comment: I call it a bug too, because while remembering last filter could be handy at times, there is no way to NOT remember and clear the filter history. Oh, and it still happens in VS2013!

Comment: Same for VS 2013, under \12.0\Find

Comment: Bugged me in VS2010, then again in VS2012, then again in VS2015, now it bugs me in VS2017, christ. What is it? Oldest bug competition?

Answer (score 31):

Duh, change the filter to * and Visual Studio will remember it and it will perform an unfiltered search. Not sure why I didn't think of it sooner.

Comment: Nice workaround, but just emphasises how stupid this behaviour is.

Comment: If only that worked. I set it to `*` many times. It always reverts back to 'spec*.cs' from that ONE TIME MONTHS AGO THAT I WANTED TO SEARCH FOR THOSE FILES!!!

Answer (score 15):

This happens in Visual Studio 2017 as well, and I can't find the registry to clear. My workaround is to set the file type to `*.*` instead of clearing it.

Comment: This worked in 2017 for me, which is nice as it is the simplest solution. Setting it to `*` alone did not work for me.

Comment: Apparently Visual Studio 2017 uses a private registry... you can find the keys described in other answers there https://stackoverflow.com/a/41122603/1328536

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio has the "feature" of storing this information in the registry.  You can change the registry manually, but since we need to change the registry after every filtered search, it is useful to have a .reg file to do it.

Save as 'Reset Search in Visual Studio.reg':

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Find]
"Query"="Entire Solution"
"Filter"=""
"Filter 0"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Find]
"Query"="Entire Solution"
"Filter"=""
"Filter 0"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Find]
"Query"="Entire Solution"
"Filter"=""
"Filter 0"=""
```